# DataGridView freezing when attempting to load xml data

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I cant figure out why my program freezes while importing xml data. It only does the first colomn before freezing.

```
<ADDONSWOTLK>
  <ADDON>
    <NAME>Ackis Recipe</NAME>
    <STATUS>Most Recent Version</STATUS>
    <DOWNLOAD>http://www.mediafire.com/download/4s4qomta4u51ajm/AckisRecipeList-3.3.5.zip</DOWNLOAD>
    <VERSION>N/A</VERSION>
  </ADDON>
</ADDONSWOTLK>
```

That there is my xml file.

```
try
{
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\\Addons.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

I have played around trying  multiple ways to read the xml files to hope I get a different outcome, with no luck.

Properties of the datagridview

```
this.dataGridView1.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Table;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 9);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(699, 549);
        this.dataGridView1.StandardTab = true;
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
```

I do have my datagridview in a panel so I can hide it and show it easily. I have no clue if that is the cause, I am just really confused and cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: How do you have `ds` declared?

Comment: Is your program throwing an exception? If so, what exception?

Comment: `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` ?